# Tag Cleanup - Vote for the following proposed tag changes

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are several proposed tags changes lingering about here on meta. I thought I'd capture them all here, each one as a separate answer, and let people vote on them.

## Awaiting Review

- [make `database-backup` a synonym of `backup`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/953/2660)
- [merge `database-restoring` and `restore`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/615/1396)
- [`Scaling` and `scalability`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/582/2660)
- [Delete `hashbytes`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/567/1396)
- [Make `sql-agent` a synonym of `sql-server-agent`.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/543/2660)
- [Delete `schema`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/409#409)
- [Rename `tuning` to `query-tuning` and blacklist forcing explicit choice between this and `database-tuning`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/483#483)
- [Rename `sql` to `sql-language` and blacklist to prevent abuse](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/484#484)

---

## Completed

- [Make `sqlcmd-mode` a synonym of `sqlcmd`.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/474#474) - **completed**
- [Rename `sql-server-2011` to `sql-server-2012`. Make `denali` a synonym of `sql-server-2012`.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/456#456) - **completed**
- [Merge `locking` into `locks`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/453#453) - **completed**
- [Delete `xmltype`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/435#435) - **completed**
- [Delete `columns`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/410#410) - **completed**  made synonym of [database-design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design)
- [Delete `add-column`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/406#406) - **completed**
- [Delete `data-migration`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/388#388) - **completed**
- [Delete `database`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/392#392) - **completed**
- [Merge `restore` and `recover`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/386#386) - **declined**
- [Delete `query-help`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/385#385) - **completed**
- [Rename `azure` to `sql-azure`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/384#384) - **completed**
- [Delete `mysql-replication`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/383#383) - **completed**
- [Delete `pg-restore`](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/tag-cleanup-vote-for-the-following-proposed-tag-changes/387#387) - **completed**

**If you downvote a suggestion please explain why in a comment.**

Comment: I'd leave sql as-is.  There are a lot of questions tagged SQL on SO.

Answer (score 10):

[Remove](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/removal-of-mysql-replication-tag) the [mysql-replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql-replication) tag. Use  [mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql) and [replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replication) together instead.

Comment: [mysql-replication] was merged into [replication]; all the questions already had the [mysql] tag anyway

Answer (score 9):

Delete [columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns).

What's the point of it? Existing questions tagged with it should instead use [database-design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design) or nothing at all.

Comment: seems like columns is now a synonym of [tag:database-design]

Answer (score 9):

How about the [denali](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denali) and [sql-server-2011](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2011) tags being renamed to [sql-server-2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) as that was the official name announced at this morning's PASS Summit keynote.

Comment: Sweet. I think `denali` should be a synonym, `sql-server-2011` renamed.

Comment: Agreed. Made the same suggestion on this meta SO thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98692/sql-server-2011-vs-sql-server-denali

Answer (score 8):

[Remove](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/appropriate-use-of-the-query-help-tag) [query-help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-help). We already have [query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query).

Comment: I merged these tags

Comment: Neither of these are even needed, per-se. The whole point of posting a query is to get help, and at that point you should be identifying the platform.

Answer (score 8):

Delete [add-column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-column).  What's the point of that?

We already have [columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns) (itself of questionable value).

Answer (score 8):

Merge [locking](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locking) into [locks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locks).

I don't see the need for both, because while discussing one you will almost assuredly be discussing the other.

Thoughts?

Comment: I prefer locking (a concept) over locks (a thing), but yeah I don't see the need for both.

Comment: The only reason I can see to use the locks tag, is if it is a very specific question over which type of lock to expect in a given scenario.  These questions, in my mind, are encapsulated by the locking concept.

Comment: Better as a synonym, again this could adversely affect searching if people aren't aware of the exact taxonomy.

Answer (score 8):

Do something about [model](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model) .. First thought is synonym of [database-design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design)

Comment: Synonym of `database-design`?

Comment: agree - though it probably needs to come off some of the questions it's currently on

Comment: we need to encourage some other guys to vote in here :)

Comment: @Jack hope you don't mind, I edited the answer with nick's suggesiton

Comment: Vote here on the synonym: http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/database-design/synonyms

Comment: Fairly ambiguous term. I think the appropriate strategy would be to re-tag to 'data-model' or 'database-design' where this was more meaningful.  However it's still worth thinking about naive searches.

Answer (score 7):

Index and indexing tags should be merged.

Answer (score 7):

Alias [privileges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privileges) to [permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissions)

Comment: I think I'd prefer to have it the other way around. In my experience, DBMSes tend to call them [tag:privileges], while OSes call them [tag:permissions]. At present, only [tag:permissions] has a tag wiki entry.

Answer (score 6):

Delete [pg-restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pg-restore) and similar tags that add platform names to generic database concepts.

Questions relating to generic database concepts should be tagged separately with the platform and the operations. So, for example, [pg-restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pg-restore) should instead be [postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) and [restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restore). Contrast this to [mysqldump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysqldump), which is about a specific tool and so merits its own tag.

Comment: this was all the result of overtagging on a single question, which I retagged: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4755/postgresql-corrupt-primary-key-inconsistent-table

Comment: `Delete pg-restore and similar tags that add platform names to generic database concepts.` I don't know all the tools on all the platforms. If you see one come up like this, flag the question for us mods to see, and tell us in the flag (or better, in a comment on the Q) why that flag is no good.

Comment: pg-restore, rman and mysqldump are all "specific tools" AFAIK - is there something special about mysqldump that merits its own tag?

Comment: @JackDouglas - Didn't know that about `pg-restore`, actually. I assumed its intention was equivalent to `postgresql` and `restore`. Thus, in this case I would say [tag:pg-restore] is OK as long as the question is about the specifics of getting that tool to work. ([tag:mysqldump] retroactively merits its existence because there are so many questions about the specifics of getting that tool to work.)

Comment: @JackDouglas - Alternately, perhaps we should delete [tag:mysqldump] as well and recommend people use [tag:mysql] and [tag:export] together?

Comment: I don't know what is most pragmatic here but I think a single tag covering backup/restore/export/import and perhaps a seperate tag covering recovery would be cleanest. The Status Quo is not so bad though?

Answer (score 6):

Delete [hashbytes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashbytes)

Seems a bit too specific to be helpful?

Comment: Definitely. A tag for one SQL Server function? Nope.

Answer (score 6):

Remove [microsoft](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft).  Any tag should refer to a product more specific than just the company that makes it.

As suggested by gbn and implemented by COTW, could be merged with generic [vendor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vendor) tag.

Comment: +1 inclined to agree with this - all but two questions tagged [tag:microsoft] were actually questions about [tag:sql-server]

Comment: Change to merge with [tag:vendor]?

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells added

Comment: Credit where credit is due - [tag:vendor] was actually @gbn's idea :)

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells CLARIFIED!

Comment: You guys are like research professors. Or Wikipedia editors.

Comment: I've retagged a lot of questions with gratuitous use of Microsoft (often in combination with [tag:sql-server]). The remaining questions are mostly to do with certification or where the poster mentions they've contacted Microsoft support. Maybe we should add tags [tag:certification] and [tag:support-contract] ?

Answer (score 5):

Rename [azure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure) to [sql-azure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-azure) to distinguish it from Windows Azure and make it consistent with the tags for Microsoft's other products.

Comment: agreed, and this is done

Comment: @Jeff - I would delete [tag:azure] as well so others don't use it anymore. Or was it your intention to leave it there for the OS? (In which case I would make it [tag:windows-azure].)

Comment: @JeffAtwood ... why? Was there really a strong sense of people coming to DBA and mistaking azure as being about something _other_ than data storage?

Comment: @Nick those fall off nightly

Comment: @jcolebrand - Okie doke.

Answer (score 5):

Delete [database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database). What purpose does it serve?

If the question is about selecting a database platform then it should be tagged with [database-recommendation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-recommendation).

Comment: [This is done.](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/399/blacklist-a-tag-please-devs)

Answer (score 5):

Rename [tuning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tuning) to [query-tuning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-tuning) and blacklist [tuning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tuning) forcing explicit choice between [query-tuning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-tuning) and [database-tuning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-tuning)

Comment: Again, tags can get used in searches, so not having a 'tuning' tag could be counter-intuitive if you weren't familiar with the taxonomy in use.

Comment: don't forget `index-tuning` too

Answer (score 5):

Delete [error-17828](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-17828).  Not worthy of it's own tag.  It was created solely for [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/8921/2660).

Answer (score 5):

merge [database-restoring](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-restoring) into [restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restore)

Answer (score 4):

Delete [xmltype](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xmltype).

We already have [xml](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xml). Two of the three questions tagged [xmltype](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xmltype) are already tagged [xml](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xml), and the third can easily be retagged as just [xml](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xml).

Comment: +1 sounds right to me - xml is not big enough to justify more than one tag here

Comment: @JackDouglas - Well, as a mod you can now execute on these requests. :) Is there something the mods are specifically looking for before implementing a requested tag change?

Comment: Thanks Nick, this one is now done (and xmltype is now a synonym for xml) - are there any other up-voted suggestions that haven't been actioned?

Comment: @JackDouglas - Status for each proposal is in the original question.

Comment: so it is! I'll have a look at the others tomorrow :)

Comment: but please nudge me if it looks like I've forgotten...

Comment: Again, re-tag where inappropriate, but xmltype is IIRC an [actual data type in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb04cre.htm) and therefore potentially meaningful in context.

Answer (score 4):

Rename [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) to [sql-language](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-language) and blacklist [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) to prevent abuse

Comment: There are a lot of questions on SO tagged 'SQL'.  I think it might be confusing to ban the tag, particularly if migrating questions from there.  However, I think anything referring specifically to SQL Server should get re-tagged.

Comment: Also `SQL-language` is redundant - Structured Query Language Language?

Comment: @JNK the other option is keep [tag:sql] which means retagging numerous questions from those who think SQL Server is called SQL - which do you prefer? :-)

Comment: I think retagging from SQL to SQL Server makes sense, though.  They will need to be ANYWAYS since we pretty much always want a RDBMS tag on there when possible, right?

Comment: @JNK I think you [were right to say](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/587/1396) [tag:rdbms] is too general if it is used for anything other than Qs like: "How does an RDBMS keep data consistent when there are multiple users?"

Comment: @JackDouglas - COTW showed some good use cases in chat so I removed the suggestion.  There are some valid uses about generic solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Make [sql-agent](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-agent) a synonym of [sql-server-agent](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-agent).  The former was created for [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10293/2660).  The latter is older and is the [correct term](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx?ppud=4) for the service.

Answer (score 4):

Migrate [percona](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/percona) to [percona-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/percona-server). I created the [percona-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/percona-server) tag with the intention of making [percona](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/percona) a synonym, but don't have the required score.

Since Percona Server is the Percona's (the company) database offering, I think the `-server` bit is of higher importance.

Comment: By that logic wouldn't we need to rename oracle too?

Comment: What do people actually call it when they refer to it elsewhere?

Comment: @JackDouglas "By that logic wouldn't we need to rename oracle too" I think Oracle is fine, as they don't refer to their product as 'Oracle Server' (Maybe 'Oracle Database', but that's redundant). Percona (the company) calls their product 'Percona Server'. I think the separation of product and company is important here. What if the 'SQL Server' tags were just 'SQL'!

Comment: SQL Server can't be SQL because of confusion with the SQL language - but we'll never need a percona tag for the company will we? Unless there is a case of possible confusion, I favour brevity

Comment: @JackDouglas The problem is Percona offers many things, such as [tag:percona-toolkit]. Personally, I favor removing any confusion by explicitly separating their offerings to how they identify the products.

Comment: we have [tag:mysql] and [tag:mysql-workbench]?

Answer (score 4):

transaction-logs as a synonym for logs or vice-versa.  My preference would be for transaction-logs to be the canonical entry but logs has a lot more questions on the tag.

Answer (score 4):

We have [scaling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scaling) and [scalability](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scalability). Make one a synonym of the other.

Answer (score 4):

Remove [learning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) and/or merge into [learning-resources](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-resources)

Answer (score 4):

Convert [model](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model) to [data-model](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-model)

Answer (score 1):

Merge `ssis` and `ssis2008` and just use `ssis`. For version specific features, the sql version tag can be included.

Comment: What if some user has some problem using eg ssis2012 in combination with sql-server-2008?

Answer (score 0):

Please make [sqlcmd-mode](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlcmd-mode) a synonym of [sqlcmd](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlcmd).

Comment: No, they're separate things.  SQLCMD-MODE can refer to SSMS running SQLCMD scripts, but SQLCMD itself is a separate application.

Answer (score 0):

Make [database-backup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-backup) a synonym of [backup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup).

Vote on the synonym here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/synonyms

Answer (score -3):

Though they technically mean different things, [restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restore) and [recover](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recover) should be made synonyms of one common tag (or maybe one be the synonym of the other).

Propose how exactly this should change in the comments to this answer.

Comment: there are only 2 and 3 questions, respectively; this can probably stay as-is for a bit longer while we figure out the distinction

Comment: Restore and Recover do not mean the same things. Recover means "omg that shit is gone" and restore means "i need the version from yesterday"

Comment: @jcolebrand - Right, but I wonder if each merits its own tag, as opposed to a more generic tag that covers both scenarios.

Comment: @Nick they each deserve their own tag, as there is no "common" ground for the two. One is something we should all be prepared to do daily, the other is disaster recovery.

Comment: @jcolebrand - OK, I'm with you on this. I'll edit the wikis for those two tags to stress the difference.

Answer (score -4):

Delete [data-migration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-migration).

We already have [migration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration) and [data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data). In most cases [data-migration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-migration) can simply and aptly be replaced by [migration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration).

Comment: the [data] tag is far too generic to exist and I have destroyed it. I then renamed [data-migration] to simply [migration]

Comment: @JeffAtwood the data tag I agree with, however data-migration and migration can be two different things here. It's entirely possible that a person has questions about migrating an instance of an cloud server, for instance. Let's not be too haphazard with the renames. I told Nick to post it on meta to get discussion from the site's power users.

Comment: @JeffAtwood - agree with jcolebrand.  'Data Migration' is a widely used term.  Migration can get used in other contexts, such as shifting VMs around different hosts.

Comment: Or migration from Oracle to SQL Server or vice versa. I agree that migration and data migration are not synonyms.

Answer (score -4):

Delete [schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema).

It is too generic to be useful. Most questions tagged with this are better served by [database-design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design).

Comment: Some DBMS platforms (e.g. SQL Server) have a feature called 'schema'.  Re-tagging inappropriate use to 'database-design' is certainly sensible, but 'schema' itself can mean something quite specific.

Comment: +1 for deletion - I'd argue that it is too localized - and that the added complication of the clash with the generally accepted meaning of 'schema' means the bar should be even higher before we accept it as a 'good' tag

Comment: long conversation in The Heap bookmarked [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/conversation/tag-scope-and-especially-schema)

Comment: If you look at the wiki for this tag, it actually could be considered a synonym for database-design. Perhaps we need to come up with two different schema tags, one for design, the other for the logical division of tables within a database?

Comment: Isn't [schema] also defined in the SQL standard?

Answer (score -4):

Remove [configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration)

It's too generic to be useful.

Comment: Take a look at the 18 questions currently tagged with that.  Seems like an appropriate tag to me. Broad but still useful as a categorization field.

Comment: @NickChammas I don't think so, since configuration is NOT transferrable between RDBMS implementations.  You really should at the least have `mysql-configuration`, `sql-server-configuration`, etc.

Comment: Tags are categories.  You want MySQL configuration questions?  You search for [`[mysql] [configuration]`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql+configuration). SQL Server configuration? Search for [`[sql-server] [configuration]`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+configuration).  Works better this way. Why? Because the tags are "normalized". :>