# Make sql-developer a synonym of oracle-sql-developer

Tags: discussion, tagging

Make [sql-developer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-developer) a synonym of [oracle-sql-developer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-sql-developer).  "sql-developer" is ambiguous and people have tagged general development questions with that in the past.

Asking here instead of in the [Tag Cleanup](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/382/2660) post because that one's getting unwieldy.

Comment: Separate requests per tag is sufficient in most cases. Are we sure that [tag:sql-developer] should always be the equivalent of [tag:oracle-sql-developer]?

Comment: @jcolebrand - [Yes.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/sql-developer/info)

Comment: I think this makes sense.  The other meaning of `sql-developer` would indicate an off-topic question for the most part.

Comment: @JNK - Agreed. Can we make it so?

Answer (score 3):

Done

filler to meet arbitrary minimum requirements

Comment: Are they really arbitrary?

Comment: the minimum answer requirements, yes.

Comment: I see that all existing questions have been retagged `oracle-sql-developer`, but I don't see that `sql-developer` is a synonym of that tag.